# Using FOR in a batch file for deleting specific files at once

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, directory, del

I'm trying to search for specific files in all directories and subdirectories inside my batch file path in order to delete them at once :

```
for /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /B /S %~dp0bb1-*.png bb2-*.png bb1_0*.png bb2_0*.png style.css *.thumb 2^>nul') DO del /q "%%A"
```

What do you think of this code ? Are there things that could be changed/improved ? Is it reliable and safe from unwanted deletion ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Torieu. As described in https://stackoverflow.com/help, this forum is for making code achieve the desired effect. This is not the place for suggestions or criticism. None of the questions are on-topic for SO. Please delete the question here and ask in a forum where it may be on-topic. You might try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have in mind that `dir /B /S %~dp0bb2-*.png` and `dir /B /S bb2-*.png` could give different result: `%~dp0`  (where the script resides)  and current directory could differ!